# export to excel from html table excel formula not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel-formula, export-to-excel

I have below code for export excel from HTML table . my question is, after export file when user add excel formula for calculation's ,excel formula not working.

> i  googled last 3 days but not success  when i add 2  2 other cell
>   formula working fine. but 
>   exported data cell formula not working

[image]

> Example when i add `=SUM(D2,D3)`   not working . Anyone help me
>   this

```
   function ExportoExcel() {
        var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
        var textRange; var j = 0;
        tab = document.getElementById('printtable'); // id of table

        for (j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) {
            tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";
            //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
        }

        tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
        tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table
        tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, ""); // remove if u want images in your table
        tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
        {
            txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
            txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
            txtArea1.document.close();
            txtArea1.focus();
            sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
        }
        else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
            sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));

        return (sa);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: How is it not working? If it just displays the formula without calculating then the cell could be formatted as text. If you're getting an actual error message then something else is going on.

Comment: after export file. when user add formula in excel file. that's not working